# Why is the printing of array elements in average slower than the printing of single objects in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I made a test to see the differences between accessing array elements and single objects by printing their values into the CLI:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    int v1 = 1;
    int v2 = 2;
    int v3 = 3;
    int v4 = 4;
    int v5 = 5;
    int v6 = 6;
    int v7 = 7;
    int v8 = 8;
    int v9 = 9;
    int v10 = 10;

    std::cout << "Array output:" << std::endl << std::endl;

    auto t_start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "1. value: " << a[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. value: " << a[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. value: " << a[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. value: " << a[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5. value: " << a[4] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "6. value: " << a[5] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "7. value: " << a[6] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "8. value: " << a[7] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "9. value: " << a[8] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "10. value: " << a[9] << std::endl;

    auto t_end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Variable output:" << std::endl << std::endl;

    auto t_start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "1. value: " << v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. value: " << v2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. value: " << v3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. value: " << v4 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5. value: " << v5 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "6. value: " << v6 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "7. value: " << v7 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "8. value: " << v8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "9. value: " << v9 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "10. value: " << v10 << std::endl;


    auto t_end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout<< std::endl << "Time passed with array: "
              << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end1-t_start1).count()
              << " ms\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout<< std::endl << "Time passed with variables: "
              << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end2-t_start2).count()
              << " ms\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

On the first implementation (MingW/g++ under Windows 10,cmd.exe), the printing of values inside array elements is in average 3 **milliseconds** slower than using single scalar objects:

Table for Windows, g++/MingW:

```
                Array Elements:            Single Objects:   

1. Run          13.9609 ms                 9.529 ms
2. Run          11.9031 ms                 8.0936 ms
3. Run          13.3706 ms                 9.5264 ms
4. Run          12.5302 ms                 8.4723 ms
5. Run          14.4679 ms                 9.9688 ms
6. Run          12.3989 ms                 8.4326 ms
7. Run          12.8719 ms                 10.1851 ms
8. Run          10.9138 ms                 7.4481 ms
9. Run          12.8971 ms                 9.4094 ms
10. Run         11.9045 ms                 7.9391 ms
11. Run          9.9192 ms                 8.4047 ms
12. Run         13.4106 ms                 10.0296 ms
```

On the second implementation (g++ under Linux Ubuntu), the printing of values inside array elements is 3 **microseconds** in average slower than using single scalar objects:

Table for Linux Ubuntu, g++:

```
                Array Elements:            Single Objects:   

1. Run          0.013 ms                   0.008 ms
2. Run          0.012 ms                   0.007 ms
3. Run          0.013 ms                   0.008 ms
4. Run          0.014 ms                   0.009 ms
5. Run          0.012 ms                   0.008 ms
6. Run          0.013 ms                   0.008 ms
7. Run          0.013 ms                   0.009 ms
8. Run          0.014 ms                   0.009 ms
9. Run          0.012 ms                   0.008 ms
10. Run         0.013 ms                   0.009 ms
11. Run         0.012 ms                   0.009 ms
12. Run         0.012 ms                   0.008 ms
```

---

My Question:

- Why is the printing of values in array elements in average slower than the printing of values in single objects in *C++?

*Info: I do not know if the printing of array elements is in general in average slower, independent of a specific language.

Comment: I am confused why Mingw is soo slow.

Comment: Fundamentally, accessing an object is direct.  Accessing an element of an array requires calculating the offset, location or address of the element (from the beginning of the array).  Many modern processors can do this in one instruction.

Comment: Optimized build or debug build? It matters.

Comment: @drescherjm It is because of the Windows system in general in comparison to Linux.

Comment: Could be the time it takes to print to stdout is worse in windows versus linux

Comment: @JesperJuhl Optimized build.

Comment: By direct access, I mean that the compiler already knows the address of the object.  Only a pointer needs to be dereferenced.  For a member of an object, the compiler emits instructions to adjust the value in a pointer (by the offset of the member), then dereferences the pointer.  These operations should be in nanoseconds.

Comment: Print the assembly language for the function.  The assembly language will give more insight into the thought process of the compiler (at the given optimization level).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at the [generated assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ze2PGc) you can notice that the compiler replaces loads of array elements and scalars with constants because their values are known at compile time.

---

You measure the time it takes to format and output the elements of the array, as well as flush the output stream on each element (with `std::endl`), which involves a syscall.

Loading an element from an array is much shorter than that. Loading a CPU register from L1 cache takes 4 CPU cycles (less than 1 nanosecond on a 5GHz CPU), from memory (last level cache miss) on i9-i9900KS ~215 CPU cycles, on Ryzen ~280 CPU cycles.

There should be no measurable difference between loading an element from an array or from a (scalar) variable. Loading an element from an array may involve a bit of index arithmetic in the generated assembly, but that may be hardly measurable.

---

When I put a loop around your timings to let the CPU increase its frequency to its max, page fault pages in and warm-up CPU cache; and replace `std::endl` with `'\n'` I get the following timings:

```
Time passed with array:     0.029154 ms
Time passed with variables: 0.029286 ms

Time passed with array:     0.027148 ms
Time passed with variables: 0.027587 ms
```

This is to show that there is no measurable time difference between accessing array elements and scalar variables (but it is still measuring `std::cout` times).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Ok, that gives an answer to the distinction between formatting and putting out vs. accessing. But why does it in average print out the array values slower than the ones from the scalar types?

Comment: @ Can be CPU kicking into a higher frequency, page faults, cache warm-up. To get accurate measurements the CPU must be locked into a constant frequency, the benchmark should do a few loops to warm-up the cache and page fault pages in. Only after measure the time. Added the times to the answer.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica: When you have surprising benchmark results, try doing the test in the other order.  So the other one has to pay startup costs inside the timed region, and/or run with the CPU not yet at max turbo.  Or make separate programs (one for array, one for scalar).  That way you can see that the extra cost "for array" is actually the extra cost for the first call to `std::cout.operator<<(int)`, or just that the CPU frequency hasn't warmed up yet.  Of course if you know enough to do that, you'd know enough to do some warm-up runs *before* the timed region, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your test, writing stuff to cout takes WAY more time than just accessing this stuff in memory.

To make the matters worse, it probably doesn't even read value from array or variables, as the value is already known in compile-time. It probably just uses constant in both cases.

To prove all that, just try comparing with time of output of hard-coded constants. And try to compare it with time that calculation and output of the sum of those numbers takes.

We can't be sure of the reason why first output is slower though. That just depends on how OS works with those output streams.

Comment: IMHO, a better method of verification is to print the assembly language. :-)

Comment: You need to know assembly for that, and people who understand assembly tend to understand that stdout would take much longer than a read from RAM